# How to store values from input field in React?

Tags: reactjs

How to read all the entered input values comma separated.
Here i am trying to set html using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. The html contain three input field, how can i read valued entered in all the three input field.

Suppose I entered `24` in first input field then `12` in second input field and `2` in third input field . So now i want to save all the values in state variable comma separated i.e.

24,12,2

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";


const data = {
  htmltag: `<div><p><input type = 'text' /></p><p><input type = 'text' /></p><p><input type = 'text' /></p></div>`
};



export default function App() {

  const [state , setState] = React.useState("")

  const handleChange = () => {
    setState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      state: 
    }));
    }

  return (
    <>
      <div onChange = {handleChange}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.htmltag }}
      />
      <button> Submit </button>

      <p>values comma separated: {state} </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does `data` come from an external source? Do you control what HTML is in there?

Comment: Yes i can have a bit of HTML control

Comment: Can you add a ```name``` property to each input field?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly urge you not to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. You are basically telling react it's can't manage or reference the elements in there. So you are only left with direct DOM traversal.

But I'm going to assume you have a good reason that isn't apparent from your example.

---

If you give the parent element an `id` then you can pull values out with a `useEffect` hook.

```
<div
    id="my-inputs"
    onChange={handleChange}
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.htmltag }}
/>
```

Now use an effect to pull data from those ids and put them in state with something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#my-inputs input'))
  setState(  
    inputs
      .map(input => input.value)
      .join(',')
  )
})
```

Comment: is there any other way like using useRef and then using querySelector get all the input values, as i am beginner in React and learning

Comment: Before I answer that are you sure you want to be using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? Because this is easier without that. See [the official docs on form handling](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Comment: Actually i am getting this HTML from API so i have to use ```dangerouslySetInnerHTML```

Comment: So possibly will not be able to modify in HTML part, so is there any other approach ? If you come across any of such idea please do tell.

Comment: See my update. Basically, you add an id to the container HTML that you _can_ control, and then use DOM methods to get values out.