# How to store values from input field that is set by dangerouslySetInnerHTML React?

Tags: reactjs

How to read all the entered input values comma separated. Here i am trying to set html using ````dangerouslySetInnerHTML```. The html contain three input field, how can i read valued entered in all the three input field.

Suppose I entered 24 in first input field then 12 in second input field and 2 in third input field . So now i want to save all the values in state variable comma separated i.e.

But `handleChange` function is not working

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = {
  htmltag: `<div><p><input type = 'text' /></p><p><input type = 'text' /></p><p><input type = 'text' /></p></div>`
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");


  const handleChange = () => {
    console.log(" Inside of handleChangeOption Scenario");
    const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#my-inputs input"));
    const formDataArray = inputs.map(input => input.value);
    console.log(formDataArray);
    const x = formDataArray.toString();
    console.log(x);
    setState(x);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
  }, [state]);


  return (
    <>
      <div
        id="my-inputs"
        onChange={handleChange}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.htmltag }}
      />
      <p>values comma separated: {state} </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You have added the handleChange to the div and that doesn't change. You need it to add the handler to the form elements.

Comment: is that `htmlTag` something you can move to the actual JSX of the component?

Comment: My question is do you need to have the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? Do you not have control of the html input fields and you're retrieving them from an API? If not I would just write the `<input>` within the `<div id="my-input"><input ...`

Comment: Actually i am getting this HTML from API so i have to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML.So possibly will not be able to modify in HTML part, so is there any other approach

Comment: There is, I'll write it up. It's hacky, but it's possible.

Comment: Hi @codingwithmanny How It's hacky?

Comment: @Coding see answer below. The issue that I see is if the htmlData is dynamic, in the useEffect, it could trigger it to reload, which would not be ideal. I haven't experienced it, but I did manage to get it working.

Comment: Are you posting duplicate posts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62663266/how-to-store-values-from-input-field-in-react

Comment: A kind off, actually i don't want to use useEffect for fetching values

Comment: useEffect isn't fetching values. it's the hook, in this case, that is running when the component first loads. You need someway to wait for the input fields to render because you can't grab them, otherwise it would just return null and it wouldn't detect the input fields.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do a mix of query selectors on and local state management.

Click the **"Run code snippet"** below.

```js
// main.js

const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const htmlData = {
  htmltag: `<div><p><input type="text" placeholder="Enter text here" /></p></div>`
};

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  
  const onKeyUp = event => {
    setData(event.target.value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const divId = document.querySelector('#my-inputs');
    const input = divId.querySelectorAll('input');
    if (input && input.length > 0) {
      input[0].addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
    }
  }, []);
  return <div><h3>HTML Generated:</h3><div
        id="my-inputs"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlData.htmltag }}
      /><hr /><h3>Result:</h3><code>{JSON.stringify(data)}</code></div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
code {
padding: 10px;
background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Your code will work for single input and its a wrong way